# In Coq, is there a way to prove a premise of a hypothesis conveniently?

Tags: coq

I have `H : P -> Q` in my proof context, and I need `Q` to complete my proof, but I don't have any evidence of P:

Is there a tactic or anything else that can
make the premise `P` a new goal, then replace `P -> Q` with `Q`
after the goal `P` was proved.
Then I can use `Q` directly to prove the original goal.

However, I can also use `assert (HP : P)`
then use `(H HP)` to get a `Q`, but I have to copy `P` by hand, it is inconvenient (especially when `P` is long, and `H : P -> Q` is still there).

> I read [this](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html) but got nothing useful, maybe I miss that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is the tactic `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pierre Jouvelot that you are looking for the `apply` tactic (and I invite you to accept his answer). To complement this answer, I will propose something closer to forward reasoning as your question implies.

You don't need to understand the following but it defines a `forward` tactic that does what you want:

```
Ltac forward_gen H tac :=
  match type of H with
  | ?X → _ => let H' := fresh in assert (H':X) ; [tac|specialize (H H'); clear H']
  end.

Tactic Notation "forward" constr(H) := forward_gen H ltac:(idtac).
Tactic Notation "forward" constr(H) "by" tactic(tac) := forward_gen H tac.
```

Then you can apply `forward H` to generate a goal for `P`. In the original goal, `H : P -> Q` is replaced by `H : Q`.